# Graph with closed path of length $\leq 4$.

Tags: graph-theory, discrete-mathematics

Assume $G=(V,E)$ with $\forall v \in V: \deg(v) \geq d$ and $d \geq 2$ such that $|V|= d^2$. Then there is a closed path of length $\leq 4$ in $G$.

Some hints would be helpful :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fix $v\in V$. There are at least $d$ vertices that connect to $v$. Call this set tier 1. If any of these connect to each other we have a closed path of length $3$ containing $v$ and we are done. If not, each of these connect to at least $d-1$ other vertices. Call these tier 2. But $d(d-1)$ tier 2 vertices plus the $d$ vertices from tier 1 plus $v$ equals $d^{2}+1$ which is one too many. Therefore, two of the tier 1 vertices must connect to the same tier 2 vertex creating a cycle of length $4$.

Comment: @RossMillikan  That is what I am saying. We know that $|V| = d^2$ and if we are allowed to map each of the tier 1 vertices to $d-1$ vertices we will have one too many. Therefore, one of the tier 2 vertices must be connected to two tier 1 vertices. Is that correct? I have edited my response to make that clearer.

Comment: Yes, I like this version better.  +1

Comment: Nice proof. The argumantation is thus: Assume that the vertices in $T_2$ are connected to exactly one vertice in $T_1$. Then $|T_2| \geq d(d-1)$ which gives us $d^2+1$ vertices which are too many. Thus there exists a vertice in $T_2$ which must be connected with more than one vertice in $T_1$.